# Update from EF 3.1.6 to EF 7.0.7

Tags: entity-framework-core

I recently updated the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package from version 3.1.6 to 7.0.7.

I have noticed that with the new package in place, a `DELETE` statement is executed every time I add a new row to a table called `Commands`, and I cannot figure out why.

The source code has not changed. Before I present a lot of code, I will show you the specific method and the EF Core logger output. Maybe someone has an idea based on that.

Method

```cs
private async Task<int> AddCommandToDatabase(Tracker t, string msg, TrackerCommandType type)
{
    await _context.Commands.AddAsync(new Command()
    {
        CommandType = type,
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
        Message = msg,
        TrackerId = t.TrackerId,
        CommandDirection = CommandDirection.SENT,
        CommandStatus = CommandStatus.OPEN
    });

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

(The Tracker reference comes from a table called `[Trackers]` not `[TrackerConfig]`).

Output for package in version 3.1.6:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [Commands] ([BatteryLevel], [CommandDirection], [CommandStatus], [CommandType], [Date], [DeviceStatus], [Message], [RollCounter], [StepCounter], [Time], [Timestamp], [TrackerId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11);

SELECT [CommandId]
FROM [Commands]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [CommandId] = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Output from package in version 7.0.7:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [Commands] ([BatteryLevel], [CommandDirection], [CommandStatus], [CommandType], [Date], [DeviceStatus], [Message], [RollCounter], [StepCounter], [Time], [Timestamp], [TrackerId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[CommandId]
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11);

DELETE FROM [TrackerConfig]
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [TrackerConfigId] = @p12;
```

I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: No, DELETE isn't executed before every INSERT. It's only executed if you actually remove something. `AddAsync` doesn't add anything and shouldn't be used unless you use a rare algorithm for generating IDs like HiLo.

Comment: Maybe there is some code in `SaveChangesAsync`, which do additional manipulations? Also check in debugger before calling `SaveChangesAsync`  - `_context.ChangeTracker.DebugView`

Comment: This code smells a bit like the "repository-over-ORM" *anti* pattern. A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. It doesn't need low-level CRUD methods, it detects and persists changes to *all* the objects it tracks. The method `AddCommandToDatabase` can easily execute 42 DELETEs if there are 42 pending removals. That's simply not how EF Core is used

Comment: The normal way of using EF Core is to create a DbContext in a `using` block or a DI scope, make any changes you need to objects you load from it, or attach using `Add/Update` then persist all changes in a single transaction with `SaveChangesAsync`. If you don't want the changes, just dispose the DbContext.

Comment: What is `TrackerConfig`? EF Core doesn't create such a table. Does your code use such an object? Was the DbContext configured to use an interceptor?

Comment: Is there any code that removes something from a list? Remove something from one tracked entity and add it to another? What do the classes and tables look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos and Svyatoslav Danyliv, I was able to identify the issue. It turned out to be an anti-pattern. To facilitate serialization, I had set an FK (foreign key) property (aka related entity) to null.

This behavior wasn't a problem when using ServiceLifetime.Scoped, but I recently switched to ServiceLifetime.Singleton and forgot it. Consequently, when I call SaveChangesAsync, EF Core deletes the entity without the required FK.

As a result, I mistakenly attributed the issue to the new library.

For future readers, here are at least three better ways to handle this situation:

1. Use projection to an accurate ViewModel using .Select(...)
2. Utilize AsNoTracking()
3. Alternatively, use the [JsonIgnore] attribute.